# JavaScript not running in Script Editor

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, web-part, iframe

I have a script editor web part on a page in my site. I have the following code in it:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        document.getElementById("myframe").style.height=$('#myframe').contents().find('#divContent').clientHeight;
    });
</script>
```

Currently it is meant to change the height of an iFrame based on the size of the contents inside. It is currently not changing anything.

Why would this snippet not run when the page is loaded and set the size of the frame?

EDIT:

```
<iframe width='90%' src='//????.sharepoint.com/sites/test/AppBrightBanner/Pages/BannerAppPart.aspx?ASpeed=500&PauseTime=4000&Effect=random&NavThumbs=false&ThemeColor=rgb(0%2C%20114%2C%20198)&ThemeStyle=bar' 
frameborder='0' scrolling='no' seamless id="myframe"></iframe>
```

iFrame which is being used and when added to a content editor is being stuck at 150px in height, but when not in editor it is completly stripped and not viewable.

HTML from F12. Are these classed as outside the iframe?

[image]

Comment: You are referencing the iframe and the div within the iframe with ID ("#" used in the selector). Can you check whether that the div in the iframe has ID "divContent"?

Comment: Added a snippet of the layout when the page has loaded. I am now not sure if this is classed as being inside the iframe or outside...

Comment: Looks OK. You are refer it the right way. It can be that the iframe content is not ready when you try to get the height of the div. Can you change the script between the document ready to: alert($('#myframe').contents().find('#divContent').clientHeight). This should alert the height of the divContent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to address this by changing some of the initial script to firstly run when the frame has loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
document.getElementById("myframe").onload = function()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("myframe");
    var height = height=document.body.clientHeight;
    document.getElementById("myframe").height = parseInt(height-document.getElementById("myframe").offsetTop-8)/1.9+"px";
}
</script>
```

I have learnt I cant dynamically set the height for my frame from the content inside because they are on different domains (sub domains count as seperate unfortunately).

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the jQuery reference on your page.

Also make sure the IDs of the content are correct.

Open the browser's console and check what exception you get. :)

**EDIT:**

As I understood, you are trying  to resize the iframe to fit it's contents. The reason why your code doesn't work is taht #divContent is not actually on the page (it's in the iframe).

Tkae a look at [this question and it's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it)

Comment: I have added the reference which is in my edit and all the id's are correct. The console is now not complaining but the height is still not being set to the correct value.

Comment: Can you provide us with your html structure?

Comment: I have edited my inital question to answer this,

Comment: @JamesMichaelLucas , is #divContent inside the iframe? or is it on the current page?

Comment: Another update in my main section. I am now not sure if this classes as indie the iframe or not.

Comment: @JamesMichaelLucas see my updated answer

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at it. When trying the content their I get no changes still. I get` Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "" from accessing a frame with origin "". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.` in my F12 which is coming from the fact that the iframe content is held on a subsite.

Comment: What do you actually need this for? I think there are some better approaches than using iframe?

Comment: The iframe in question is set to show a slideshow of images. It was developed as a third party app which has its own subsite and holds the images. It uses an iframe to display on pages or through its own web app. The web app cannot be customized as much, but the iframe height is only as big as the parent (as it is in a web part) which is fixed to around 200px.

Comment: What if you set the height='100%' as you do for width='90%' ?

Comment: No change. I initially hoped this wold work. But a height % makes no changed but a fixed height is fine (e.g. 200px). This is fine if all screens were the same but on laptops it looks strange with a large white space below. (The images fit as expected but the iframe keeps its fixed height).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39279/discussion-between-james-michael-lucas-and-gintas-k).

Answer (score 0):

There are few reason that might preventing your code to run

- Check jQuery reference added in your script editor.
- If you have added jQuery reference and still it is not working try your code by placing it in Content Editor WebPart.

If you still face issue then track console in debugger of browser. And let me know if solved you issue.

Thanks

Comment: Neither of those options seem to have worked, I have added this reference `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` but it does not work in either.